# CV2.imread() Python image not loading and no error displayed

Tags: python, image, opencv, ubuntu

In my python flask program hosted on Ubuntu using Apache2, the program I wrote usually is able to use imread to compress and process an image. The code now is not being able to access the image even though the file path are correct and it is an existing file and does not return any error message. This seems to occur with any type of image not depending on the type of file and the code sometimes returns a none type is not subscript able if that is related to this issue. Thanks for any help in advance! The code:

```
img = cv2.imread(file_path)
height, width, _ = img.shape
roi = img[0: height, 0: width]
_, compressedimage = cv2.imencode(".jpg", roi, [1, 90])
file_bytes = io.BytesIO(compressedimage)
```

Comment: How did you find out that the image is not read? What happens if you display the image with `img = cv2.imshow("image", img)` after `img = cv2.imread(file_path)`?

Comment: Try printing `img.shape` immediately after reading the image.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. The code is currently running in a flask program on a server and I have attempted the imshow which has not worked. The code stops reading past the cv2.imread and does not run any other lines after it.

Answer (score 0):

> code sometimes returns a none type

It looks to me like the file path you are supplying might be incorrect. I am saying this because `cv2.imread` does not throw an error for a non-existent file path:

```
img = cv2.imread("/non/existent/image.jpeg")
```

Rather it returns None:

```
img is None
```

(returns `True`). Your code would then fail on `img.shape` line. So you could either check that the file path is correct before supplying to cv2.imread:

```
assert os.path.isfile(file_path)
```

or you could `assert img is not None` after doing the `imread` and before going further.

EDIT:

I see that you are claiming that you have checked that the file path is correct and the file exists. But then you are yourself saying

> the code sometimes returns a none type is not subscript able

This is because of `img[0: height, 0: width]` where you are trying to index/subscript None.

You can check that if you type `None[0]`, you get the same error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`. So I still feel that the image path is not correct or it is not a valid image file (has some other extension than the ones listed [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#imread)). In both cases you get a `None` on `imread`.

Since the code snippet you've provided is a part of a larger app, the problem could be somewhere else such that sometime the file path is valid and sometime it is not? I am only guessing at this point.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have tried testing the filepath before supplying it to cv2 and it has returned True.

Comment: @Python123, so `img.shape` is running properly and then on the roi line `img` becomes None?

Comment: Image shape usually runs properly but sometimes it doesn't and I thought it would be tied to the issue. The code essentially downscales an image from any size to less than 1 MB and makes file bytes for the image so is there anyway to do this without cv2 and with PIL or some other way to bypass this issue altogether?

Comment: When you say "Sometimes it doesn't"; do you check whether those times, the file is present at the location passed to imread?

Comment: I have checked that the file exists when the cv2 imread stopped working and have printed the file path and looked it up in the file explorer to confirm it is an image.

Comment: Use os.path.isfile to check. You want to avoid human error

Answer (score 0):

You can't expect `cv2.imshow()` to work inside `flask` or `apache`.

- When `apache` starts it generally switches user to a user and group called `www` so it doesn't have the same environment (`PATH`, `HOME` `DISPLAY` and other variables) as when you run something from your Terminal sitting in front of your screen.
- Nor does the `www` user even have the same Python modules installed if you added them to your own user.
- It also doesn't have a `tty` where it could apply `cv2.waitKey()` to tell if you had pressed a key - to quit, for example.
- It also doesn't have permission to draw on your screen - or even know who you are or which one of the potentially many attached screens/sessions you are sitting at.

Maybe consider looking at the [logging](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/logging.html) module to debug/monitor your script and log the image path and its file size prior to `cv2.imread()` and its `shape` and `dtype` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
The solution was to "clean" the path.

I had spaces and "+" in the filepath, and by replacing both with "_" the files are now properly read by cv2.imread().